# Use subscripts in labels in schematic added from Circuitlab

Tags: support, circuitlab

I need the components in my circuits to be labelled using sub-scripts like \$R_1,\ R_2,\ Z_{in}, V_{DS},\$ etc., Is there any way to do so?

Comment: You don't need a subscript for R1, R2, D5, etc.  They are normally written just as I did here.

Comment: Yes. But it was better if I could write \$V_{DS}\$ instead of VDS

Comment: Using subscripts is pretty academic. Any schematics drawn by a real engineer for a real circuit will do what Olin of W5VO suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unaware of really any EDA tool that allows you to use subscripts. A common workaround is to use underscores to imply a subscript, such as `V_DS` or `Z_IN`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I usually exported the image as `svg` from circuitlab and then edited it to add subscripts to the labels. So I just wanted to know that something like that is possible here.

Answer (score 1):

For my graduate work, it was recommended for people to use Microsoft Visio to recreate their circuits with nice formatting and the capability to do subscripts for labels. It's still clunky for that if I remember right, but at least it's possible there. Visio has a nice library of elements for circuit schematics. Obviously, you can't simulate a circuit from Visio...

Comment: The latex package `circuitikz` is also a good alternative..